# Dyanamic start of activity on check of some condition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, bundle, if-statement

Actually in my application i have set an activity as main activity in which i am checking the condition on some text bundle values retrieved in this activity which is starting the activity on checking if edittext length is null or not and according to that opening respective activity on each condition but its giving me an error that:-

```
11-16 12:40:48.588: E/AndroidRuntime(456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.avigma.shpoonkle/com.avigma.shpoonkle.CheckActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 12:40:48.588: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.avigma.shpoonkle.CheckActivity.onCreate(CheckActivity.java:19)
```

i am providing my CheckActivity class please help me...thanks in advance...

```
 public class CheckActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle i=  getIntent().getExtras();
        String a=i.getString("a");
        String b12=i.getString("b12");
        String c1=i.getString("c1");
        String d=i.getString("d");
        String e111=i.getString("e111");
        String h=i.getString("h");
        Intent i1;

        if((a.length()>1)&&(b12.length()>1)&&(c1.length()>1)&&(d.length()>1)&&(e111.length()>1)&&(h.length()>1))
        {
            i1 =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShpoonkleActivity.class);
        }
        else
        {
            i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Test.class);
        }
        startActivity(i1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: while getting extras, use String c1=i.getString("b12",null); and check whether c1 is null or not then proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check line 19 . nullPointerException means you are trying to access object/variable which is actualy null .

at a rough glance `if((a.length()>1)&&(b12.length()>1)&&(c1.length()>1)&&(d.length()>1)&&(e111.length()>1)&&(h.length()>1))` seems the line where a/b12 ... might be null

Answer (score 0):

You have set CheckActivity as your main launcher activity,if I don't get you wrong.Then how would it be possible to send extras with your intent to start that activity? that activity would be automatically called when your app is opened up.

Also,if you will check `getIntent().hasExtra("a")` and same for other strings,you will get it `false` always as there won't be any such extras appended to your intent.

So basically,your way of working is not proper.Use some other solution to achieve your needs.

Comment: Doesn't matter...putting it as main activity is sufficient for the problem you are getting. simply,you just can't have extras in very first intent which calls your main activity in your app.that was my point! you are the one who appends extras to the intent,and default intent to start your app won't provide you those extras with intent.

Comment: thnx i get your point actually its not posssible i should endeavour for some other way of retrieving other activity edittext's text in the main activity...is that so..??

Comment: If you have some hard coded texts in those edittext than you can retrieve it.But again,if you want to remember what user puts there and next time,at the time of starting app,you need to check that value and redirect user accordingly,then it is not possible.because everytime you will get null as its value in your main activity.You can use SharedPreference there to remember user's text and use it later in your main activity.that will work for you.

Comment: I have used Shared Preferences in that activity to save the the edittext's text and its working fine but cant find the way further to retrieve that shared prefrences stored text in main activity and if that is possible to retriev i am ambigious that is it fine when we retrieve that in main activity..

Comment: yes...it is perfectly fine.but you need to maintain its default value and according redirection of activity in your app.